# Find out the id of the anchor tag which has been clicked

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, hyperlink, anchor

These anchor tags are being created at run time. There are 4 anchor tags,when any of them are clicked, application is redirected to same page,But MY PROBLEM IS hOW DO I KNOW WHICH ANCHOR TAG (a1/a2/a3/a4) has been clicked. I want the id of the anchor tag which has been clicked, and do remember anchor tags are being created at run time.
Thank you for your time.

```
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<a id='a1' rel='facebox' display='block' href='info.aspx'>Click1</a>"));

    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<a id='a2' rel='facebox' display='block' href='info.aspx'>Click2</a>"));

    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<a id='a3' rel='facebox' display='block' href='info.aspx'>Click3</a>"));

    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<a id='a4' rel='facebox' display='block' href=info.aspx'>Click4</a>"));
```

Comment: Simply you can pass query-string like "info.aspx?id=1" and based on that server side use Request.QueryString.

Comment: Do you want id of anchor tag on info.aspx ?

Comment: @MicrosoftDN it is fine with me(both cases) whether i find the clicked id on this cs page or on info.aspx

Comment: BUt i will prefer on this cs page only

Comment: Why don;t you use query string parameter as suggested by @mit and use it later on info.aspx.

Comment: Sir, actually, there is no "info.aspx" kind of page in my application, rather it is href='#info' where info is the id of a div, and an iframe is placed there which calls my required page

Comment: <div id="info"  style="display:none;" > 
     <iframe id="iframe1"   src="Default.aspx" width="750px" height="650px" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
  
     </div>

Comment: actually i am using javascript and css to open a popup using facebox and that popup is opened in div "info"

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be create anchor in following way-

```
  for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
   {
       var htmlanchor = new HtmlAnchor
       {
          ID = "Click_ID" + i,
          HRef = "#info",
          InnerText = "Click" + i
       };

       htmlanchor.ServerClick += new EventHandler(htmlanchor_ServerClick);
       PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(htmlanchor);
   }
```

The event handler would be-

```
   void htmlanchor_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Response.Write(((System.Web.UI.Control)(sender)).UniqueID); // This will print id of anchor button you clicked
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for you time sir, i have looped and created different HtmlAnchor tags at run time and i have ID of each HtmlAnchor, but how do i know which has been clicked????

Comment: DN ...I dnt understand how do i know the id of HtmlAnchor which has been clicked

Comment: nice work, i am getting the clicked htmlanchor but htmlanchor.attributes.add("rel","facebox")  is not working completely.